# document.click to remove class on page not behaving properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a global style of dropdowns which toggle between open and closed when their menu icon is clicked, but also close whenever anywhere else on the page is clicked. The way in which I'm opening or closing this dropdowns is by adding or removing a class called "open" to the parent of the dropdown.

The idea of that (to be more clear) is that the normal class of the dropdown has display: none; set on it, but if it's a descendant of something with the class "open", then it has display: block;

So, without further ado, here's what I have so far:
"openable" is a class of 'parent' elements which can be clicked on to add the "open" class.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.openable').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("open")){
            $(this).removeClass("open");
        }
        else{
            $(this).addClass("open");
        }
    });
});
```

On it's own that actually works fine - it acts as a decent enough toggle for the dropdowns. Of course, clicking anywhere else won't close the dropdowns.

My apparently non-functioning close script is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).click(function(event) {
        var clicked = $(event.target);
            if(clicked.hasClass(".open")){
        }
        else{
            if($(".open").length > 0){
                $(".open").each(function(){
                    $(this).removeClass("open");
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

With that script on the page, dropdowns cease to work altogether, and console isn't throwing up any errors for me to work off of.

Any better way of doing this?

Thanks

edit: html markup is something like

```
<li class="navItem dropdown openable">
<span><img src="img/settings.png"></span>
  <ul class="subNav hubDrop">
    <li>Nav item 1</li>
    <li>Nav item 2</li>
    <li>Nav item 3</li>
    <li>Nav item 4</li>
</ul>
        </li>
```

for each one. the li tag there is within another ul (remember, this is for dropdown menu essentially)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/cxVty/) - Since you haven't provided any HTML I mocked up some elements...

**Update**: You don't specify if more than one element can be 'open' at once; in your current solution they can be, so I kept that behavior. However, to limit it to one being open you can add `$('.open').not(this).removeClass('open');` inside the `.openable` click handler.

---

Part One: Why not just use [`.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass)

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.openable').click( function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("open");
    });
});
```

Part Two: No need for a second ready handler; in the first, add this:

```
$(document).click( function(e) {
    var clicked = $(e.target).closest('.openable');
    if ( clicked.length == 0 ) {
        $(".open").removeClass('open');
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! I also added the updated bit to limit it to one open. In my original implementation I actually used toggle, but not toggleClass (forgot), and had issues with it toggling already hidden elements to hidden. This worked well, and with the right document structure.

Answer (score 1):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/omutam/1/edit)**

just played around a bit (don't know your markup.)

```
<div>
<h2 class="openable">ICON 1</h2>
<div class="cont"></div>
</div>
```

```
$('.openable').next('.cont').hide();
$('.openable').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.opened').removeClass('opened');
    var d = $(this).next('.cont');
    var visib = (d.is(':visible')) ?
       /*yes*/   d.slideUp() :
       /*no */  ($('.cont').slideUp()) (d.slideDown().prev('.openable').addClass('opened')) ;
});

$(document).click(function(){
    $('.cont:visible').slideUp().prev('.openable').removeClass('opened');
});
```

Comment: This works well enough, but with a bit of a different and more roundabout way than I'm trying to do - I don't actually need to touch the child element and set it as visible. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can just do `$(document).click()`, it's not wrong but you never click the document itself, you click children of.

I have a very similar menu system and I capture an event this way:

```
 $('.navTab').mouseover(function (event) { navEvent($(this), event.type); });
```

Then remove all "open" and reapply "open" to the selected item.

I believe you don't want to capture all document click events.  [jQuery Event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

Answer (score 0):

How about making everything but the openable classed elements execute your click method?

```
var openable = $(".openable");
$("div, h2").not(openable).click(function(){
    $('.cont').slideUp().prev('.openable').removeClass('opened');
});
```

Comment: If you want there to be only one open dropdown, then that's not going to work.